# What can change the include_path between php.ini and a PHP file

Tags: apache, include, php

I've inherited some code on a system that I didn't setup, and I'm running into a problem tracking down where the PHP include path is being set.

I have a php.ini file with the following include_path

```
 include_path = ".:/usr/local/lib/php"
```

I have a PHP file in the webroot named test.php with the following phpinfo call

```
 <?php
      phpinfo();
```

When I take a look at the the phpinfo call, the local values for the include_path is being overridden

```
                 Local Value                                        Master Value
 include_path    .;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\     .:/usr/local/lib/php
                 Apache2.2\pdc_forecasting\classes
```

Additionally, the php.ini files indicates no additional .ini files are being loaded

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path           /usr/local/lib
Loaded Configuration File                   /usr/local/lib/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files     (none)
additional .ini files parsed                (none)
```

So, my question is, what else in a standard PHP system (include some PEAR libraries) could be overriding the include_path between php.ini and actual php code being interpreted/executed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Outisde of the PHP ways

```
ini_set( 'include_path', 'new/path' );
// or
set_include_path( 'new/path' );
```

Which could be loaded in a PHP file via `auto_prepend_file`, an `.htaccess` file can do do it as well

```
phpvalue include_path new/path
```

Comment: Grumble grumble .htaccess.  I combed through the http.conf looking for overrides and forgot about .htaccess.

Answer (score 3):

There are several reasons why you are getting there weird results.

- include_path overridden somewhere in your php code. Check your code whether it contains `set_include_path()` call. With this function you can customise include path. If you want to retain current path just concatenate string `. PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path()`
- include_path overridden in `.htaccess` file. Check if there are any `php_value` or `php_flag` directives adding dodgy paths
- non-standard configuration file in php interpreter. It is very unlikely, however possible, that your php process has been started with custom `php.ini` file passed. Check your web server setup and/or php distribution to see what is the expected location of `php.ini`. Maybe you are looking at wrong one.

Comment: +1: Even if you are basically repeating everything that has been said already.

Answer (score 2):

An `.htaccess` file or Apache's configuration (`httpd.conf`) could also be responsible.

Check for anything that looks like the following:

```
php_value include_path something
```

More information about that behavior here:

> [PHP: How to change configuration settings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php)

---

The other option would be the use of [`ini_set()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) or [`set_include_path()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php) somewhere, but considering that your `test.php` only contains [`phpinfo()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) (and assuming that `test.php` is called directly), I doubt that is your problem.